# How to remove onclick delay and keep the fast scrolling in mobile web application

Tags: android, mobile, click, scroll, delay

I am developing a Web application on OS Android using PhoneGap. 
For a quick response from the user interface buttons, I use the following solution: 
http://code.google.com/intl/ro-RO/mobile/articles/fast_buttons.html
The problem is that when I use this solution, scrolling slows down because the event handlers are attached to the following events: ontouchstart, ontouchend, ontouchmove.
How to make a quick response from the buttons and keep the fast scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Try executing codes in the events ( ontouchstart, ontouchend, ontouchmove,...) in another thread and post the results to main thread.